# Delphi android drag and drop buttons

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

**SITUATION**

I am using Delphi Seattle and I want to develop a very simple game.

[image]

As you can see here I here I have a grid layout and the grey squares are `TButtons`. My goal is to be able to move (for example) the top-left button with the number 2 above the other button below with the number 2. I have written this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1DragDrop(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Data: TDragObject;
  const [Ref] Point: TPointF);
var t,d: TButton;
begin

 T := TButton(Sender);
 D := TButton(Data.Source);
 T.data := T.data + D.data; //sum 2 + 2

 //... other code, not relevant ...

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1DragOver(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Data: TDragObject;
  const [Ref] Point: TPointF; var Operation: TDragOperation);
begin

 if ((Sender is TButton) and (Data.Source is TButton) and not(Sender = Data.Source)
     and (TButton(Sender).Text = TButton(Data.Source).Text) and (TButton(Data.Source).Text <> '')) then
  begin
   operation := TDragOperation.Move;
  end
 else
  begin
   operation := TDragOperation.None;
  end;

end;
```

When I run this as 32-bit windows program it works fine. I am able to click on a button with the number 2 and perform a drag & drop on another button having the number 2.

---

**PROBLEM**

This program in my Android device doesn't work because I cannot perform the drag and drop. I have already seen some example online about this, but I cannot find a specific solution for my problem.

What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, on Android the "drag and drop" fmx service is not working, just on Windows and IOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).